# Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, json.net

I have an object which holds an array of nodes, its json serialization looks like this:

```
{
  "$type": "Toolbar, MyNamespace",
  "DisplayIcons": true,
  "NodeHolder": {
    "$type": "NodeHolder, NodeHolderNamespace",
    "RootNode": {
      "$type": "NodeHolder, NodeHolderNamespace",
      "Id": 0,
      "Title": "root",
      "Children": [
        {
          "$type": "NodeHolder, NodeHolderNamespace",
          "Id": 10001,
          "Title": "Homepage",
        },
        {
          "$type": "NodeHolder, NodeHolderNamespace",
          "Id": 10002,
          ...
}
```

My problem is that when enumerating the Children arraylist it cannot cast the objects to NodeHolder, I get an error message: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type NodeHolder. The type is being defined on the json already, not sure what to try next

Serialization code:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Deserialization code:

```
Toolbar tb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Toolbar>(json);
```

Comment: foreach (NodeHolder child in node.Children)
          ...

Comment: Show the whole code: how you deserialize your object, what are the object types you deserialize into

Comment: I have added the serialization and deserialization lines

Comment: And where is the code where you access the deserialized object and the definition of `Toolbar`, `NodeHolder`. Show ALL relevant information so that we can help you.